# ElasticSearch: Group by on the partial field value

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, resthighlevelclient

My data will look like

```
{
  {"id": "c1/RESOURCE-Id", ,,,},
  {"id": "c2/RESOURCE-Id", ,,,},
  {"id": "abc/RESOURCE-Id", ,,,},
  {"id": "c1/RESOURCE-Id-2", ,,,}
}
```

I want to fetch the unique resource-ids.

Result should be

```
RESOURCE-Id
RESOURCE-Id-2
```

So the plan is to do groupby in combination with `regex` on field `id`, but I am unable to figure out the syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex your data using below script and then you can apply collapse on resource field for group by.

```json
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index2"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
        def id = ctx._source.id;
        if (id.contains('/')) {
            def res = id.splitOnToken('/')[1];
            ctx._source.resource = res;
          }""",
        "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Now you can use collapse on resource field as shown below:

```json
POST index2/_search
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "resource.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "resource",                  
      "size": 5
    }
  }, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```